# Why won't Silverlight handle the conversion of my custom float property

Tags: silverlight, xaml, typeconverter

In a Silverlight 4 project I have a class that extends Canvas:

```
public class AppendageCanvas : Canvas
{        
    public float Friction { get; set; }
    public float Restitution { get; set; }
    public float Density { get; set; }
}
```

I use this canvas in Blend by dragging it onto another control and setting the custom properties:

[alt text http://www.farseergames.com/storage/share/PropertyInBlend.Png](http://www.farseergames.com/storage/share/PropertyInBlend.Png)

When I run the app, I get the following error when InitializeComponent is called on the control containing my custom canvas:

```
Failed to create a 'Windows.Foundation.Single' from the text '0.0'
```

[alt text http://www.farseergames.com/storage/share/SilverlightError.Png](http://www.farseergames.com/storage/share/SilverlightError.Png)

I'm not sure why Silverlight isn't able to convert this property from it's string representation in Xaml, to the float that it is.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Native Text Syntaxes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638655(v=VS.95).aspx#native_text_syntaxes) sub-topic lists the types that Xaml natively knows how to convert.  Fundementally the primitive types supported are `double`, `int`, `bool` and `string`.

Answer (score 0):

Got this from twitter friend Cameron Albert:

> That is odd, I wonder if it would fail
>   if that was a double?

Switched to doubles and no more error.  Still curious that floats don't work.

Comment: First question, if you add your own type converter or value converter, can you store the value? There may not be a single/float converter by default.

Comment: Second, internally in Silverlight for performance reasons, many doubles have single precision, and as a result this may an artifact of that.