# Silverlight XAML BUG

Tags: silverlight, xaml

Why if I put this into a xaml dictionary used under Silverlight the compiler founds an error.

```
<Color x:Key="colorBackDark" A="255" R="150" G="170" B="190" />
```

In WPF XAML everything is OK.

BTW the error is present no matter of the silverlight version used.

It looks like that is some kind of parser error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume the error you're getting is something like the following:

> Failed to create a 'System.Byte' from the text '255'

The XAML parser in Silverlight only knows how to handle `double`s, `int`s and `bool`s.  The properties `A`, `R`, `G` and `B` in the `Color` struct are all `byte`s, which the Silverlight XAML parser doesn't know how to handle.  The XAML parser in WPF, on the other hand, does know how to handle these values, so that's why you're not getting an error in WPF.

The [MSDN documentation for the `Color` struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color(v=vs.95).aspx) lists a number of ways to create a `Color` value in XAML in Silverlight.

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672076/why-wont-silverlight-handle-the-conversion-of-my-custom-float-property) was asked a while ago about why `float`s can't be used in XAML in Silverlight either.

Comment: Message from the future: Hello 2012, This answered me too today(2014)!