# Silverlight - Managing Color Resources - Errors

Tags: silverlight, templates, styling

I'm trying to manage the resources in my Silverlight 5 app built in VS2012. For the purpose of theming, I've pulled out all the color codes in my various custom templates, and moved them to a seperate resource file so they can be changed independently of the main templates.

I've declared them as follows:

```
<Color x:Name="ButtonForeground">#FFFFFF</Color>
<Color x:Name="ButtonBackground">#004760</Color>
<Color x:Name="ButtonAltBackground">#0089B7</Color>
```

While this builds and runs fine, each of these lines has two "errors" that come up whenever I build the project:

- Cannot add content to an object of type "Color"
- TypeConverter Syntax error encountered while processing initialization string '#ColorCode'. Element attributes are not allowed on objects created via TypeConverter.

With 30 colors defined, I have 60 build errors in the error list window, even though the project builds and runs fine, and this is detracting from real errors when they come up.

This also has a knock on effect of not enabling my color ResourceDictionary to be referenced, as they are unable to find the theme file with the Colors in, and because the dictionaries that depend on them don't work, I'm unable to reference them in turn, so none of my templates are found. (This is leading to another 100+ errors which don't stop the app building and running)

Can anyone explain to me why these errors are here, and what I need to do to make them go away?

Update: I Have also tried using the following approach, which has no problems with the XAML and works as far as the resource dictionaries are concerned, but throws an exception at runtime:

```
<Color x:Name="ButtonForeground" R="255" G="255" B="255"><!--#FFFFFF--></Color>
<Color x:Name="ButtonBackground" R="0" G="71" B="96"><!--#004760--></Color>
<Color x:Name="ButtonAltBackground" R="0" G="137" B="183"><!--#0089B7--></Color>
```

This looks to be related to the bug posted here: [Silverlight XAML BUG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281706/silverlight-xaml-bug)

Update 2:
I've tried the following two approaches, both work, but the commented out version causes errors, and I've removed it for that reason.

```
<VisualState x:Name="Normal">
<Storyboard>
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="BtnBorder">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ButtonBackgroundBrush}"/>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <!--<ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.1" To="{StaticResource ButtonBackgroundColor}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" Storyboard.TargetName="RbBorderBackground"/>-->
</Storyboard>
```

The live section points directly to a border object and uses it's Brush property, the commented out version points to the Brush used by the Border, and uses the Color property. The commented out version animates smoothly and looks good, the current version simply swaps the brush out immediately.

Thanks

Tristan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to user x:Key, not x:Name for resources.
The conversion error occurs when you have the x:Name attribute but not x:Key.

```
<Color x:Key="ButtonForeground">#FFFFFFFF</Color>
```

`x:Key` is used to identify resources within a ResourceDictionary, whereas `x:Name` is used to name elements (Grid, controls etc)...

Comment: Arg. Complete newbie mistake :(

Comment: good thing about making mistakes is that you learn from them :D