# Unable to define Color elements in WP8 XAML due to conversion error

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-8, colors

I'm trying to create a color in my XAML style to be reused liked this:

```
<Color A="255" R="47" G="79" B="79" x:Key="ChromeColor" />
```

It compiles successfully, but during runtime, it throws this error during initialization:

```
Failed to create a 'System.Byte' from the text '255'. [Line: 21 Position: 18]
```

Is there something I'm missing about definiting the properties?

Comment: SL parser doesn\`t know how to handle `byte`. Please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11281832/1021555) for details (the question is basically just like yours).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
<Color x:Key="MyColor">#FF2F4F4F</Color>
<SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource MyColor}" x:Key="MyColorBrush" />
```

ARGB value : 255, 47, 79, 79

Equivalent Hex : #FF2F4F4F

You can use this [color converter](http://www.zonums.com/online/color_converter/).

Comment: Oooh shoot, forgot to convert, points down for mine and +1 for yours. Think I'll go ahead and delete it.

Comment: Thanks this works. I'd still be interested in knowing why the property doesn't work as it should.